# Error when compiling c++ code in Conda environment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, undefined, conda, clang++, gsl

I'm trying to compile a c++ code in a Conda environment, but I get the following error:

```
> x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -I"${CONDA_PREFIX}"/include parallel_MCMC_newMHratio.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gsl_interp_accel_alloc", referenced from:
      _main in parallel_MCMC_newMHratio-5a5120.o
  "_gsl_interp_accel_free", referenced from:
      _main in parallel_MCMC_newMHratio-5a5120.o
  "_gsl_interp_alloc", referenced from:
      _main in parallel_MCMC_newMHratio-5a5120.o
  "_gsl_interp_eval", referenced from:
      _main in parallel_MCMC_newMHratio-5a5120.o
  "_gsl_interp_free", referenced from:
      _main in parallel_MCMC_newMHratio-5a5120.o
  "_gsl_interp_init", referenced from:
      _main in parallel_MCMC_newMHratio-5a5120.o
  "_gsl_interp_linear", referenced from:
      _main in parallel_MCMC_newMHratio-5a5120.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I get the same error also when compiling with:
`clang++ -I"${CONDA_PREFIX}"/include parallel_MCMC_newMHratio.cpp`

I also set the CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT environment variable to match MacOSX10.10.sdk with:
`export CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT="/opt/MacOSX10.10.sdk"`
but nothing has changed.

**UPDATE**

when compiling with `clang++ -Wall parallel_MCMC_newMHratio.cpp -o a.out -I"${CONDA_PREFIX}"/include -L"${CONDA_PREFIX}"/lib -lgsl` it works.

But when I execute `./a.out` I get the following:

```
dyld[2208]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgsl.23.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/.../a.out
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libgsl.23.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgsl.23.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

Can someone please help me? I would be very grateful.

Comment: It likely needs to be told to look for libs in `${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib`

Comment: @merv Please, see the update in the question: there seems to be a conflict between gsl libraries.

Comment: Are you trying to build something to run outside of the original Conda environment? The rpath failure can imply that it was compiled to run in the environment, but the environment is not activated when trying to run it.

Comment: @merv the environment is activated when I run it, but in any case I get the rpath error.